# Decomposing a matrix with polynomial elements into a polynomial with matrix coefficients

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, polynomials, vector

Let's say I have a matrix, $\mathbf{M}$, that is polynomially dependent on a single variable, such as

```
M = {{15 + a^2, a + 5 a^2}, {a - 5 a^2, 2}}
```

and I want to find the individual matrices, $\mathbf{A}_i$, such that

$$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{A}_0 + a \mathbf{A}_1 + a^2 \mathbf{A}_2 + \ldots$$

How do I do this? What do I use if there are multiple variables? Also, can I specify that certain symbols are not to be treated in this manner, e.g.

```
M = {{15 + a^2, a + 5 a^2}, {a - 5 a^2, 2 c}}
```

where the constant matrix would be `{{15, 0}, {0, 2 c}}`? Ideally, this should be applicable to vectors and tensors, also.

Comment: Note: this is intended to be a canonical question.

Comment: Consider e.g. `M = {{ArcTan[a], Zeta[a]}, {Sinh[a], Sqrt[a]}}`.  The only route seems to be expanding  every entry in Taylor series.

Comment: @Artes you are correct, but I was honestly focusing on polynomial dependent matrices.

Comment: @Artes had the right idea: Taylor coefficients are what I basically use in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a very simple way to do it:

```
Table[1/i! D[M, {a, i}] /. a -> 0, {i, 0, 3}]

(*
==> {{{15, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 5}, {-5, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
*)
```

This works even if the entries are *not* polynomials. If they are, you can replace the arbitrary maximum `3` in the `Table` index by the degree of the polynomial:

```
Max[Exponent[M, a]]
```

**Edit**

Looking at the other solutions, this solution (due to its fundamental simplicity) is the only one that works without modification for arbitrary rank tensors and *simultaneously* for arbitrary functions that can be expanded in the variable `a`, be they polynomial or not.

Comment: +1, it hadn't even occurred to me that using a derivative is perfect for this.

Comment: Alternatively: `Table[Map[SeriesCoefficient[#, {a, 0, i}] &, M, {2}], {i, 0, 3}]`.

Comment: @J.M. I think that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Accepted for simplicity and generality beyond what I asked for.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one quick way for polynomial matrices:

```
polyMat = {{15 + a^2, a + 5 a^2}, {a - 5 a^2, 2}};
Transpose[PadRight[CoefficientList[polyMat, a]], {2, 3, 1}]

{{{15, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 5}, {-5, 0}}}
```

Alternatively (as Jens hints), you can do `Flatten[PadRight[CoefficientList[polyMat, a]], {3}]`.

You can check that the matrix polynomial is reproduced with `Fold[(#1 a + #2) &, 0, Reverse @ %]`.

Comment: It works (+1)... but it's a bit complicated.

Comment: Because of the `Transpose[]`? ;)

Comment: Yes, you could have replaced `Transpose` by `Flatten`... OK - better not.

Comment: I see. The thing is that I'm comfy with the second argument of `Transpose[]` for as long as I'm dealing with tensors of rank $\leq 3$. More than that, and it's a tad complicated for me to imagine, too...

Comment: I've modified it so that one no longer needs to deal with the polynomial degree explicitly...

Answer (score 10):

First, if you don't know the degree you can compute it:

```
m =  {{15 + a^5, a + 5 a^2}, {a - 5 a^2, 2 c}};
degree = Max[Flatten[Exponent[#, {a}] & /@ Flatten[m]]]
```

(I have increased the degree of `m` to verify that intermediate zero matrices are correctly output.)

And now, with `degree` in hand, why not use a function intended for this task?

```
 Coefficient[m, a, #] & /@ Range[0, degree]
```

It works for tensors of any rank, including scalars.

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous version of this answer, `Max[Exponent[m, a]]` seems a bit more compact for computing the degree...

Comment: And, you get my last vote for today, +1.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it is more compact: thanks.  (You refer to your *old* answer. I like the new one.)

Comment: Yes; I fixed my comment now too... :D

Answer (score 9):

This is similar to J. M.'s solution, but generalized to rank $n$ tensors.

```
Clear[decomposePolyMat]
decomposePolyMat[m_, var_] := 
     Module[{rank = ArrayDepth@m, coeffs = CoefficientList[m, var],len},
         len = Max@Map[Length, coeffs, {rank}];
         Flatten[Map[PadRight[#, len] &, coeffs, {rank}], {rank + 1}]
     ]
```

Comment: `Length @ Dimensions @ m` is so common an operation that there is in fact a built-in function for this operation: `ArrayDepth[]` (formerly `TensorRank[]`).

Answer (score 2):

Starting in M9, [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) automatically threads:

```
M = {{15 + a^2, a + 5 a^2}, {a - 5 a^2, 2}};

SeriesCoefficient[M, {a, 0, #}]& /@ Range[0, 2]
```

> {{{15, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 5}, {-5, 0}}}

```
M = {{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Exp[x], Tan[x]}};

SeriesCoefficient[M, {x, 0, #}]& /@ Range[0, 2]
```

> {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}}}