# Element-wise SeriesCoefficient for matrix

Tags: matrix, series-expansion

I have a matrix expression which, when expanding with the `Series[]` command, returns

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4-O[t^5] & t-\frac{1}{4}t^3+O[t^5] \\
-t+\frac{1}{4}t^3+O[t^5] &  1-\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{8}t^4-O[t^5] 
\end{array}
\right)$$

I would like to use the `SeriesCoefficient[]` command on this matrix to return the element-wise series coefficients in matrix form - i.e.:

$$n=0~\rightarrow~ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 
\end{array}\right)$$

$$n=1~\rightarrow~ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
-1 &  0 
\end{array}\right)$$

$$n=2~\rightarrow~ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 &  -\frac{1}{2} 
\end{array}\right)$$

and so on. How would I do this? Simply running `SeriesCoefficient[Matrix[t],n]` doesn't give me anything.

Comment: Try this: `Table[1/n! D[Series[mat, {t, 0, 4}] // Normal, {t, n}] /. t -> 0, {n, 0, 
  4}]`. (I know this is a duplicate of a recent question. Let me see if I can find it.)

Comment: @march, don't forget to scale by the factorial. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Right you are! (I'm going to find that duplicate, in any case.)

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7649)

Comment: @J.M. While that wasn't the one I was thinking of, that is certainly a good candidate for marked-as-duplicate. It even has the answer by Jens that I quoted here (I have seen Jens use it before, and I learned it from them anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough:

```
m = {
   { 1 - 1/2 t^2 + 1/8 t^4 - O[t]^5, t - 1/4 t^3 + O[t]^5           },
   { -t + 1/4 t^3 + O[t]^5,          1 - 1/2 t^2 + 1/8 t^4 - O[t]^5 }
  };

Table[
 n -> Map[SeriesCoefficient[#, n] &, m, {2}],
 {n, 0, 2}
]
```

> ```
> {0 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 1 -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, 2 -> {{-(1/2), 0}, {0, -(1/2)}}}
> ```

More playfully:

```
Map[Thread @ SeriesCoefficient[#, {0, 1, 2}] &, m, {2}] ~Transpose~ {3, 2, 1}
```

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[m, {t, 0, 3}]` works directly in M9+, no need to use `Map`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you.