# Numerical value of Determinant far from what it is supposed to be

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a large matrix with numerical components and want to set the determinant to zero using the parameter `h` (see below). Naively, I would have expected that `h` sets the determinant to (approximately) zero, which isn't the case. On top of that, the order of applying the rule `sol` seems to affects the final outcome for a reason to don't see.

My output of the code below is:

```
{h -> -0.744736 + 4.42008 I}

0.0445865 - 0.0285418 I

0.0545654 - 0.114258 I
```

I am not familiar with how Mathematica handles floating point numbers so that's probably where my error lies. I have also tried to increase the precision with `SetPrecision`, but without success.

```
mat={{0.16 - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h - (1.35808 - 
  0.00120116 I) h^2 - (0.49603 - 0.00137214 I) h^3 - (0.11307 - 
  0.00105331 I) h^4 + (0.249794 - 0.000384238 I) h^5 - 
0.39204 h^6, -0.1711 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h - (1.15528 + 
    0.00267142 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 
 1. h^4), (0.0000353051 - 1.67323*10^-6 I) h^4, 
0}, {-0.1711 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h + (19.6394 - 
    0.00267142 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 1. h^4), 
0.16 - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h - (11.3534 - 
  0.00119507 I) h^2 - (0.484268 - 0.00140481 I) h^3 - (5.0714 - 
  0.00114074 I) h^4 + (0.27061 - 0.000416258 I) h^5 - 
0.42471 h^6, -0.223386 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h + (4.95742 - 
    0.00267502 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 
 1. h^4), (0.0000484431 - 2.29589*10^-6 I) h^4}, {(0.0000353051 - 
 1.67323*10^-6 I) h^4, -0.223386 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h + (41.4016 - 
    0.00267502 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 1. h^4), 
0.16 - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h - (29.348 - 
  0.00118803 I) h^2 - (0.470698 - 0.00144251 I) h^3 - (13.9095 - 
  0.00124106 I) h^4 + (0.294629 - 0.000453204 I) h^5 - 
0.462406 h^6, -0.234771 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h + (19.0123 - 
    0.00267319 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 
 1. h^4)}, {0, (0.0000484431 - 
 2.29589*10^-6 I) h^4, -0.234771 h^2 ((-0.143205 + 
   0.000186623 I) - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h + (71.32 - 
    0.00267319 I) h^2 - (0.637164 - 0.0009801 I) h^3 + 1. h^4), 
0.16 - (0.36 + 0.001 I) h - (55.3462 - 
  0.00118568 I) h^2 - (0.466163 - 0.0014551 I) h^3 - (26.6556 - 
  0.00127449 I) h^4 + (0.302655 - 0.000465551 I) h^5 - 
0.475003 h^6}};
sol = Part[NSolve[Det[%] == 0, h], 1]
Det[mat /. sol]
Det[mat] /. sol
```

Comment: Correction: I get the output `0.118714 - 0.0526506 I` (as the second output) and `0.106201 - 0.0979004 I` (as the third output); sorry, used a different matrix. But the problem still stands.

Comment: This looks like a [polynomial eigenvalue problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspected when you mentioned `SetPrecision`, you are encountering numerical errors, probably catastrophic loss of precision when calculating the determinant; your calculations do in fact need to be carried out at higher precision.

If possible, you would want to use exact numbers in your matrix, or take advantage of the arbitrary-precision capabilities of Mathematica. For instance, we can convert all machine-precision numbers to arbitrary-precision ones with a number of digits of precision equal to that of common machine-precision numbers on your machine using [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) (see also [`$MachinePrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html) in the documentation):

```
det = Det[SetPrecision[mat, $MachinePrecision]];
sol = NSolve[det == 0, h];
det /. sol // PossibleZeroQ

(* Out: 
 {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
  True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
  True, True} 
*)
```

As you can see, all those values of $h$ do bring your determinant reasonably close to zero, within machine-precision approximations.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, this is a polynomial eigenproblem. First, let's use `SeriesCoefficient[]` to [extract the coefficient matrices of your $h$-matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147360):

```
coeffs = Table[SeriesCoefficient[mat, {h, 0, k}], {k, Max[Exponent[mat, h]], 0, -1}];
```

You can then use [`PolynomialEigenvalues[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9827) to find the eigenvalues of your $h$-matrix:

```
eigs = PolynomialEigenvalues[coeffs];
```

To check the eigenvalues returned:

```
ListLinePlot[Log10[Abs[Det[mat /. h -> #] & /@ eigs]], 
             Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot of eigenvalue error]

and we see that the small eigenvalues are computed accurately, but the large eigenvalues are not. (Why this is so, I still have to do some research on.)

So, as a sanity check, let us compute the eigenvalues a little differently:

```
eigs2 = Reverse[1/PolynomialEigenvalues[Reverse[coeffs]]];
ListLinePlot[Log10[Abs[Det[mat /. h -> #] & /@ eigs2]],
             Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: another plot of eigenvalue error]

Comment: (Hopefully, when I can get my computer fixed, I'll be able to devote more time on this and other problems!)

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful! Though, does this imply that I can't assume the first few solutions actually solve the problem with reasonable accuracy?

Comment: @Nils, yes, for some reason (which I still need to do further research on), the large eigenvalues are not being computed accurately by both procedures (i.e. the normal one and the one with reversed coefficients). But, let me suggest an experiment for you to try while I'm not at a computer: evaluate `mh = Map[HornerForm, mat, {2}]`, and then try both `ListLinePlot[Log10[Abs[Det[mh /. h -> #] & /@ eigs]], Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]` and `ListLinePlot[Log10[Abs[Det[mh /. h -> #] & /@ eigs2]], Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: The problem seems to be numerically unstable, as the characteristic polynomial has reasonably large order. Hence, one subtracts two relatively large numerical values, which results in a loss of precision especially for large roots. I will try to find the roots by searching for local minima of the characteristic polynomial and see what happens.

Comment: @Nils, James Wilkinson has long warned about ever trying to do numerical stuff involving the characteristic polynomial, so a direct expansion into coefficients is out.